# ruby incompatible curb version

Tags: curb

I installed the curb gem by:

```
gem install curb
```

But when i include in my ruby code by require 'curb', it gives the following error

```
/Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curl.rb:1:in `require'" dlopen(/Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curb_core.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libcurl.4.dylib (LoadError)
Referenced from: /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curb_core.bundle
Reason: Incompatible library version: curb_core.bundle requires version 8.0.0 or later, but libcurl.4.dylib provides version 7.0.0 - /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curb_core.bundle
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curl.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curb.rb:1:in `require'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/curb-0.8.5/lib/curb.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `require'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `block (2 levels) in require'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `block in require'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `each'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:59:in `require'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:132:in `require'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/clapone/vishnew/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `require'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:53:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
from /Users/vishrutmehta/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'  
from script/rails:6:in `require'    
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please Help

Comment: Let me help you help us to answer your question by refering you to this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist

Answer (score 20):

I had the same problem. Solved it by reinstalling curl from brew and linking it in to my path

```
brew install curl
brew ln curl --force
```

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem too; I had to run

```
gem pristine curb
```

to fix it.

Comment: This fixes my issue

Comment: I had to do `gem uninstall curb` and `gem install curb -v <VERSION NUMBER>` to get it to work (after `brew reinstall curl`). No idea why `gem pristine curb` didn’t work.